# TeX command into Environment

Tags: macros, environments

How to change below mentioned latex "command" as "environment" mode

e.g.

```
\marginnotesone{sample text}
```

--->

```
\begin{marginnotesone}sample text\end{marginnotesone}
```

Please find my tex code as below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\marginnotesone[1]{%
\marginpar{%
\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont\raggedright\textcolor{cyan}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\marginnotesone{The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9}
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: the soace after "pp." is being interpreted as an end-of-sentence space on account of the period.  Two possible fixes: if aline shoiuldn't be broken at that point, use "`pp.~6`"; if line-breaking doesn't matter, input "`pp.\ 6`".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `xparse`, which has many more features than `environ` and doesn't need `\BODY`.

I also fixed a few weaknesses in the proposed code: issuing `\leavevmode` upon entering the environment helps in getting the margin note aligned in case it is at the beginning of a paragraph. Inside the `\marginpar` it avoids a spurious line when `\color{cyan}` is issued.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{marginnotesone}{+b}
 {%
  \leavevmode
  \marginpar{%
    \leavevmode\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont\raggedright\color{cyan}#1%
  }%
 }%
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginnotesone}
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
\end{marginnotesone}
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `environ` package for that. Then you merely need to replace `#1` by `\BODY`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{marginnotesone}{\marginpar{%
\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont\raggedright\textcolor{cyan}{\BODY}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{marginnotesone}
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
\end{marginnotesone}
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9
The analyst must know what information is really needed, and
obtain a representative sample, pp. 6, 9

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is I was expected result.

Comment: @RajeshN You are welcome!